# Bootstrap Stop In-Line Input and Buttons from Wrapping at Mobile Widths

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have small buttons on either side of a input text box. It displays OK at desktop screen widths. But around 700 pixels all three objects wrap to separate rows. I've tried putting them into a row and column . That only made things worse; didn't display inline even at wide screen widths.

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <button id="mnBlue" type="button" class="btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></button>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only">Blue Quantity</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="QuantityEdit_Blue" name="QuantityEdit.Blue" type="number" value="" />
                <button id="plBlue" type="button" class="btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group form-inline">

    <label class="control-label">Quantity</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <button id="mnRed" type="button" class="btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></button>
        <input class="form-control" id="QuantityEdit_Red" name="QuantityEdit.Red" type="number" value="" />
        <button id="plRed" type="button" class="btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></button>
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="QuantityEdit.Red" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The top buttons and text box in the linked screen capture shows the display I'm trying to achieve on a mobile phone sized screen. The bottom shows what is happening at mobile screen widths.

[Flickr: Example Screen Capture](https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8609/16681970436_e69d69e80d.jpg)

Comment: do you mean something like this http://jsfiddle.net/xc6stnna/1/

Comment: Yes that is very helpful, thank you!  How can the buttons be kept closer to the textbox? The right button especially has a lot of whitespace between it and the textbox.

Comment: Well I'm able to get the button to stay closer to the textbox by modifying the style sheet.     .col-xs-2  { padding-left:0; }.  Not sure if this is the best way to accomplish it.